# How to restrict a variable to contain sequence or same digits

Tags: sql

I want a variable which should contain only digits with length minimum 5 and maximum 8 and should not contain a sequence in ascending or descending and all the digits should not be same.

Example - 111111, 123456, 654321 are invalid

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You mentioned variable but are you actually asking how to create a check constraint to limit the allowable column values?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this is actually a parameter. Either way, you can't add a `CONSTRAINT` to a variable/parameter, but you can check it's value and `THROW` and error:

```sql
IF @YourVariable < 10000 OR @YourVariable > 99999999
    THROW 61234, N'Invalid value for parameter ''@YourVariable''. Value is too small or large.', 16; --Use a error number suitable for your environment.
```